# Calculate Mod of a very big number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How is it possible to calculate modulo of the following equation:

$3^{P^5} \mod P$

If $P$ is a really big prime number 174449211009120179071170527.

Thanks

Comment: Using [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) code `P=174449211009120179071170527;lift(Mod(3,P)^(P^5))` evaluates to $3$. Same thing with P^2 or P^3, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to do it by hand? or I don't know break it down to smaller problems?

Comment: Start with $3^P \pmod P$. Read [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: By little Fermat and [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242)

$\large \bmod p\!:\,\ 3^{\large\:\! p-1}\!\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 3^{\:\!\large p^{\Large 5}}\!\!\equiv 3^{\:\!\large p^{\Large 5}\bmod p-1}\!\equiv 3^{\large 1^{\Large 5}}\!\!\equiv 3\ $ by $\large\bmod p\!-\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{p\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}p^{\large 5}\equiv \color{#c00}1^{\large 5}\ \ \ $

Answer (score 0):

To find $a^M$ mod$p$, first write $M$ in binary, i.e.
$$M=c_0+c_1 \times 2 + c_2 \times 2^2 + ... +c_n \times 2^n, c_i=0 \text { or }1,0 \le i\le n  $$ The $c_i$ are easy to calculate-just keep dividing by 2 and taking the remainder. Then $$a^M=a^{c_0} \times a^{c_1 \times 2} \times a^{c_2 \times 2^2} \times ... \times a^{c_n \times 2^n}$$ and $$a^M \mod p=a^{c_0} \mod p \times a^{c_1 \times 2} \mod p \times a^{c_2 \times 2^2} \mod p\times ... \times a^{c_n \times 2^n}\mod p$$. Note that $$a^{2^{i+1}}=(a^{2^i})^2$$ and $$a^{2^{i+1}}\mod p=(a^{2^i}\mod p)^2$$ Thus all you need to do is start with  $result$ as 1 and $powerofa$ as $a$ and keep track of $powerofa= a^{2^i}$, each time squaring the previous $powerofa$ and leaving the previous $result$ as is if $c_i=0$ or multipling it by $powerofa$ if $c_i=1$, making all calculations mod $p.$ Such a program is easy to write in the language of your choice, fast to execute and uses little storage space.